# How to parse CSV table from file into D3 Chord diagram?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, oracle-apex-5.1

Recently I've started to learn how to use `D3.js`. The main point of interest are chord diagrams. My boss requested me to transfer D3 Chords as a plugin into `Oracle APEX`, where it'll read `CSV` noted data and draw chords.

**Example 1:** I've also found [an example](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2013/12/8/chord-diagrams-in-d3) (@ delimited.io, by sghall) ([github repo](https://github.com/sghall/d3-chord-diagrams)) of D3 Chord diagrams with `CSV` parser, but it is built around `D3.js` `v3.3.10`, but the current `D3.js` is `v5.5.0`.

**Example 2:** There's also a `D3.js` `v5.5.0` compatible [example here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006) (@ bl.ocks.org, by Mike Bostock). But it works directly with js matrix and has no names for groups.

*Side problem:* How to update the `hair.html` to work with the modern version of `D3.js`? **OR** how to update `Example 2` to use `CSV` input?

***Main problem:*** How to parse a `CSV` file to use it in the new `D3.js`? The best solution, I suppose, would be the closest to the examples.

Comment: Your example 1 explains in details how to create the matrix based on the CSV.

Comment: Use [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) look at the data you get back or use the `row` (`d3.csv(input[, init][, row])`) function to modify the data rows. and then construct the required matrix and use the d3v5 example.